# Issue using Vue-router in VueJS. Some of the HTML code in the <template> section is not being displayed for two of my routes

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-router

I am going to preface that I am inexperienced in vuejs so the solution may unfortunately be obvious. Regardless, I currently am having an issue using vue-router. I have two main issues at the moment. One issue is currently when I click the links for a navigation bar I have created for two routes named "Information" and "Contact", the URL changes but the contents of the changed URL is not displayed(it seems the route is not changing I think).  My second issue is some of the contents of the Information and Contact URL is not being displayed. The NavBar component(shown below) is being displayed for the Information and Contact routes but nothing else.'

The github repository is private since it has some private data and also is very long that's why I didn't include it and instead only provided some code.

I will show 3 screenshots that explain the issues I am having. The first image I have shown is a route that is working correctly, it's the route for /ProjectData. (It obviously still needs to be worked on but it is at least showing content.)
[image]

The below image is a route for /Information. It is only showing the Navbar component and the footer component(footer component is in the app.vue file). This shows the second issue I am having.

[image]

When one of the links is clicked in the navigation bar the url changes but the contents of the url are not displayed. This shows the first issue I mentioned. In this case clicking DiscoverStream Data is meant to redirect you to the /ProjectData route.

Not being redirected to other routes is only happening in the Information route and the Contact route.

[image]

I will show some of the code that I have.

```
import { createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";
import Home from "../views/Home.vue";
import Information from "../views/Information.vue";
import Contact from "../views/Contact.vue";
import ExploreScience from "../views/ExploreScience.vue";
import ProjectData from "../views/ProjectData.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "Home",
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: "/Information",
    name: "Information",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: Information
  },
  {
    path: "/Contact",
    name: "Contact",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: Contact
  }, 
  {
    path: "/ProjectData",
    name: "ProjectData",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: ProjectData
  },

  {
    path: "/exploreScience",
    name: "ExploreScience",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: ExploreScience
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHashHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes
});

export default router
```

Above is my file with my different routes.

Next I will show you my navbar which is supposed to be a component for the information route, ProjectData route, Contact route, and ExploreScience route. This is called as
NavBar in my Information.vue and Contact.vue files below.

```
<template>
<div class="Nav-Container">
  <img class="NavBackground" src="@/assets/test7.jpg">
  <router-link to="/">
  <div class="nav-child logo-container">    
    <img class="logo" src="@/assets/Logo.png" alt="Top-left LOGO which is always displayed">
    <h3 class="header">DiscoverStreams</h3>
    </div>
    </router-link>

    <!-- Nav Mobile -->

<div class="nav-child small-screen">
  <label class="smallscreen-child menu">
    <input type="checkbox" checked>
    <div>
      <span></span>
      <span></span>
      </div>
      </label>
      <a class="dribbble" href="https://dribbble.com/shots/6350574-Hamburger-switch-animation" target="_blank"><img
      src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/assets/dribbble-ball-mark-2bd45f09c2fb58dbbfb44766d5d1d07c5a12972d602ef8b32204d28fa3dda554.svg" 
      alt=""></a>
           <!--   <router-link to="/exploreScience">Explore Science</router-link>       
                <router-link to="/explore">DiscoverStream Data</router-link>
                <router-link to="/about">About</router-link>
                <router-link to="/contact">Contact</router-link > -->
    </div>
    

    <!-- Nav for large screens -->
    <div class="nav-child large-screen">
      <div class="NavigationLinks">
      <router-link to="/exploreScience">Explore Science</router-link> 
      <router-link to="/ProjectData"> Discoverstream Data</router-link>
      <router-link to="/Information">Information</router-link>
      <router-link to="/Contact">Contact</router-link>
      </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>

export default {
  name: "NavBar",

  data: () => ({
    Hamburger: require("../assets/hamburger.svg"),
    open: false,
    information: false,
    content: false,
    exploreData: false,
  }),
  watch: {
    '$route' (){
      this.open = false;
      this.information = false;
      this.content = false;
      this.exploreData = false;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Didn't show the CSS for the navbar since it's unnecessary and won't help solve the problem and is also very long.

Below is the Information.vue file.

```
<template>
<NavBar />
  <div class="about">
    <h class="hello" hello> Hello </h>
      <Hero :description="description" :image="image" />
        <Funding />
        <Affiliations />
        <Team />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
// @ is an alias to /src
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar";
import Hero from "@/components/AboutComponents/Hero";
import Team from "@/components/AboutComponents/Team";
import Funding from "@/components/AboutComponents/Funding";
import Affiliations from "@/components/Affiliations";


export default {
  name: "Information",
  components: {
    NavBar,
    Hero,
    Team,
    Affiliations,
    Funding
  },
  data: () => ({
    description: "DiscoverStream is an ongoing project being developed as part of a USGS Powell Center for Data Analysis and Synthesis Working Group led by researchers at the University of Waterloo, University of Kansas, and USGS. Questions can be directed towards Andrea Brookfield",
    image: "Ausable_river.jpg"
  })
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.about {
height: 1000px;
}

.teamsbox {
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) {
  .teamsbox {
    width: 75%;
  }
}
</style>
```

Below is the Contact.vue file.

```
<template>
<NavBar />
  <div class="container">
    <Background :description="Description" :image="image" :email="email" :phone="phone" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar";
import Background from "@/components/Contacts/Background";

export default {
  name: "Contact",
  components: {
    NavBar,
    Background
  },
    data: () => ({
    Description: "Contact",
    email: 'Email: something@something.com',
    phone: 'Phone: +?-???-???-????',
    image: 'Ausable_river.jpg'
  })
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

</style>
```

Those two above routes are not working as intended but my other two routes are and I don't know why

For instance, the below file ProjectData.vue is working

```
<template>
<NavBar />
<div class="container">
    <Map />
   <!-- <Charts /> -->
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import NavBar from "@/components/NavBar";
import Map from "@/components/Data/Map"
//import Charts from "@/components/Data/Charts"

export default {
  name: "ProjectData",
  components: {
    NavBar,
    Map
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>

.BackGroundImage{
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

</style>
```

Below is my app.vue file just in case if it is needed.

```
<template>
  <router-view />
  <Footer />
</template>

<script>
//import Navbar from "@/components/Navbar";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    //Navbar,
    Footer
  },
  data: () => ({

  }),
};
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0px ;
}

.centre-body{
  flex: 1 0 auto; 
}
</style>
```

I have tried to troubleshoot these issues for several hours but I cannot find the issue at all. I can provide more info if it is needed. Hopefully this is a simple fix.

Comment: Your path casing is inconsistent. In your Router.js file you have path: "/Information" (with a capital I), and in your router-link, you're using lower case (to="/information")

Comment: After I read your comment I checked multiple times. The I for the path and the router-link both use capital I.

Comment: I suggest to change the ```history: createWebHashHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),``` in your router file to history: createWebHashHistory(```import.meta.env.BASE_URL```), to see that it solves the problem or not!

Comment: Hello hamid, apologies for responding to your message late. I tried to attempt what you said and it led me down to converting my code from using vue-cli to vite. I currently have issues with that but once I have that working I will do what you said and see if it changes anything.